# Mule:Exact usage of db:select source attribute

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Having a flow with inbound as AMQP connector

```
<flow name="flow1">
  <amqp:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" exchangeName="INPUTEXCHANGE" queueName="INPUTQUEUE" routingKey="inputqueue" connector-ref="rabbitConnector" doc:name="AMQP"/>
  <set-variable variableName="dataCount" value="0" doc:name="Variable"></set-variable>
  <db:select config-ref="databaseConnector" target="#[flowVars.dataCount]" source="#{payload[0]['count(*)']}"  doc:name="Select">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select count(*) from tablename]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:select>
    </flow>
```

when no source is specified dataCount=[{count(*)=10}] as db select returns List of Map. What should be correct value of source attribute so that only 10 is assigned to dataCount variable. When specifying payload[0]['count(*)'] it is giving an error that payload is of byte[] which actually is the payload returned by AMQP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [user guide](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector+Reference#DatabaseConnectorReference-Attributesof%3Cselect...%3E), source is:

> The expression used to obtain the value used to calculate parameters. Default is empty, so parameters are calculated from the payload".

Source is used to "feed" the select statement parameters, not for post processing the results.

So remove the `source` attribute and compute the count the flow variable after the select with:

```
<set-variable variableName="selectResult" value="#[[]]" />

<db:select config-ref="databaseConnector" target="#[flowVars.selectResult]">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select count(*) from tablename]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>

<set-variable variableName="dataCount"
              value="#[flowVars.selectResult[0]['count(*)']]" />
```